# setup Nginx, uwsgi for RAILS app on non-root location

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, uwsgi, ruby-rack

I've set up and run a RAILS app (graylog2), and the below config made it work for root location:

```
server {
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        gzip off;
        uwsgi_modifier1 7;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3033;
    }
}
```

but I want to place my app in a path, ex: `/graylog2`

I changed my config, added   `uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /graylog2` but it did not work.

```
server {

    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    root /opt/graylog2-web-interface/public/;
    location /graylog2 {
        gzip off;
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /graylog2;
        uwsgi_modifier1 7;
        uwsgi_pass graylog2;
    }

    location / {
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, nginx/1.1.19 with latest uwsgi compiled from git

Nginx access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2013:12:26:31 +0700] "GET /graylog2/ HTTP/1.1" 404 609 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2013:12:26:31 +0700] "GET /assets/error.css HTTP/1.1" 200 458 "http://localhost/graylog2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2013:12:26:31 +0700] "GET /assets/errorlogo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 11097 "http://localhost/assets/error.css" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"
```

No nginx error.log

uwsgi.log

```
[pid: 2321|app: 0|req: 15/25] 127.0.0.1 () {42 vars in 963 bytes} [Sat Mar 16 12:24:04 2013] GET /graylog2/ => generated 609 bytes in 31 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 7 headers in 237 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

What is the right way to config nginx + uwsgi for my set up?

Comment: AFAIK uwsgi_pass adds the path in the location to the path it requests from the backend, so either do a rewrite before that.

Answer (score 0):

have you try this ? I'have use this tips with gitlab, it solve the same kind of issue...

```
location /graylog2 {
    gzip off;
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param X-Url-Prefix http://www.mydomain.com/;
    uwsgi_modifier1 7;
    uwsgi_pass graylog2;
}
```

Comment: this does not work, got all same output as my config

Comment: if it's just to serve static files, you can use try_file option (http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) and keep graylog2 on / or you can setting up a new subdomain (graylog2.mydomain.com). I have the same kind of issue with Django... You can rewrite the url router file to be compliant with /graylog rather than / .

Comment: my scenarios is my company provide me only one domain sub.mydomain.com. 
I used / to serve my home page, that why I need setup this software on /graylog2.
I know nothing about Ruby on Rails, just want to setup and use that software.
Thank you for all your advices.